# Can hit PayPal API with simple form but not with React Element (node/cors)

Tags: reactjs, express, paypal, cors

I see some similar topics but nothing addressing this specific issue.

I have a `Node PayPal API` running on an EC2 instance. It works fine when I hit it with a simple form from local host:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>PayPal Node App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Blockchainit</h1>
    <h2>Buy for 3.33</h2>
    <form action="https://cloudhookstester.net/pay" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Buy" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

But gives a CORS error (in the browser console) referencing the PayPal redirects when I use a React element:

```
class PayPalButton extends Component {
  state = {};
  handleOnClick() {
    axios.post("https://cloudhookstester.net/pay", (req, res) => {
      console.log("clicked");
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.handleOnClick} bsStyle="info" bsSize="large" active>
        Pay With PayPal
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

export default PayPalButton;
```

cors is enabled on the server:

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content$
  next();
});
```

error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6S482704WG553574G' (redirected from 'https://cloudhookstester.net/pay') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6S482704WG553574G with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

It appears that the error is coming from PayPal, not my server. What is strange is that the error does not happen, and everything works fine, when I use a form instead of a react-element.

So confused! Any thoughts?

Comment: The second one contains an API call, you would have to enable CORS on the server for it to work

Comment: I believe that cors is enabled. I edited the OP with my cors code and the exact error message. My conosle is saying that PayPal is having a problem with cors, not my server. This is odd as I can the whole thing works when accessed through a form. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure your **server** to allow cross origin requests. Try this https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html and see if you can make a request.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you much for taking the time to reply. I had cor enabled on the server, but added in your suggested code. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. I will edit my OP to reflect changes made on the server and the exact error I'm displaying in the browser console, and some other relevant information.

Comment: Could you maybe try to use Postman to test the Paypal API and see if it works that way. I did a quick google search on the Paypal API and it seems this is the way to request the API via your server https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/server-integration/#2-set-up-your-server-to-call-the-paypal-api.

Comment: I can successfully use Postman. And yes, API requests from server work. The form hits the server with a `post`, which triggers a chain of redirects that render in the browser properly. The problem is that using `axios.post` from react produces a cors error. Thanks for thinking about the issue, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Hey Hanley, Ive had another look at it and I can see that this thread has a similar issue https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/191. Maybe you could console.log the response from the server and post a screenshot to SO? That way we can debug it together quicker. :)

Comment: Hey Faris :) I really appreciate you taking the time to do some research and respond! I ended up going with a different implementation using the react element that doesn't necessitate your own server and a webhook (that does use my own server). It has been a journey but seems to finally be working. Thanks again!